# Can't figure out XPath Query using HTML Agility Pack for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Hi i have this specific HTML Code and i can't find the right XPath for this specific HTML block so i can parse it

```
<aside id="id1">
<dl class="class1a class1b">
    <dd>value1</dd>
    <dt><em>**value2**</em> value3</dt>
</dl>
<dl class="class2a class2b">
    <dd>value4</dd>
    <dt class="class3">
        <strong>**value5**<span>value6</span></strong>
        </dt>
    </dl>
 </aside>
```

The thing is that i need **value2** and **value5**

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var value2 = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//dl[@class='class1a class1b']/dt/em")
                .InnerText;
var strong = doc
             .DocumentNode
             .SelectSingleNode("//dl[@class='class2a class2b']/dt[@class='class3']/strong");
strong.RemoveChild( strong.LastChild );
var value5 = strong.InnerText;
```

Comment: I am getting a null reference exception on both values.I forgot to mention and i will fix it on my question that class1 and class2 are part of 2 values with a white space in the middle.

Comment: @AlexanderTalavari just replace `class1` & `class2` with your new values. It should work.

Comment: Thank you.Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
\\em | \\strong
```

should do the trick. you can then retrieve the text value from each node. this will find all em and strong tags in the xml fragment.
here is a [list](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp) of xpath operators.

if you need to further process the text values (in this case removing the astriks from `value5`, that will be done outside the scope of the xpath query.

Comment: The asterisks is the bold of SO.I need to retrive only this specific 2 values.Not all em and strongs.This 2 values occur only once in my HTML